# Eclipse ANdroidNo Launcher activity found. The launch will only sync the application package on the device

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to have homescreenactivity first.
But eclipe is giving me this error:
No Launcher activity found! The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
What should I do?

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/myicon"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.FootballChants.Soundboard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_FootballChants" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
             <activity
        android:name="com.FootballChants.HomeScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen" >
        <intent-filter   >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <catogory android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is for Android, but you should include that tag to get the right eyes looking at this post.

Answer (score 1):

This is misspelled:

```
<catogory android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

It should be:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```